# CSS Drop-down Menu using CSS3 and CSS3PIE

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, css, css3pie

I am a newbie in web development. I made a CSS drop-down menu using CSS3 and CSS3PIE (css3pie.com), but the drop-down doesn't work in IE6 and Firefox.

Usually this technique works in both browsers, without using CSS3 and PIE.

Does PIE have problems with CSS drop-down technique? How to fix this problem?

Here is my code (I use "if lte IE 6" hack in the code):

http://jsfiddle.net/NjQGt/

And this is where you can get CSS3PIE (PIE.htc): http://css3pie.com/download-latest

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: css3pie won't work on JSFiddle, because the .htc file has to be served from the same domain as the page. See http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=50

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the elements that PIE is used with are have position:relative set for them?

If not, make sure you've read everything here: http://css3pie.com. You might end up deciding that for such an old browser it's not worth having rounded corners and shadows – it's not exactly vital, and users of older browsers probably would prefer things to be quick rather than pretty.

Comment: Yes. I have read the PIE documentation. Unfortunately there is no drop-down menu sample in that site.

Comment: Does the menu work anywhere? I can't see the dropdown in Chrome either.

Comment: It works if I take out PIE and replace the CSS3 with CSS style.